# Android "Getting Started" Tutorial Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, gallery, viewflipper

I'm trying to build a scrollable splash screen like the ones that exist in many Google apps.  Where a user can swipe between introductory information and an indicator is given at the bottom of the page for status.

Using a `ViewFlipper` seems possible, as outlined here: http://tekartlife.blogspot.com/2014/04/changing-screen-with-viewflipper-and.html

**I'm curious what the "standard" or preferred implementation is?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and for indicators on the bottom I use this [lib](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make splash screen and a one time welcome screen in your app . Watch the tutorial http://www.androidsources.com/index.php/2015/08/06/android-splash-screen-and-welcome-screen-tutorial-using-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager` for the getting started screen and use indicators for the indicators.

You can also use best graphics like color hex codes for showing your "Getting Started" screen best.